# How to add onClick event for rows on Angular Mat-Table then go to a different page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

My question is on how to add click event on a specific row and go to next form carrying the values of the clicked row. I'm a bit confused now

```
        <!-- Position Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="itemname">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ITEM NAME </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.itemname}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Name Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="category">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> CATEGORY </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.category}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Weight Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="quantity">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> QUANTITY </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.quantity}} </td>
        </ng-container> 
        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr class="rows" mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: 
         displayedColumns;"> 
        </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: your question is bit confusing, you want to take values from the table and redirect to another page?? or same page different form?

Comment: @BlizZard my question is i want to click a row then pass their value to a different form

Answer (score 0):

Try sending the value onClick like this.

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="itemname">
     <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ITEM NAME </th>
     <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
          <ng-container ng-click="passValue(element.itemname)"> 
          {{element.itemname}} 
          </ng-container> 
     </td>
</ng-container>
```

And catch the value in js code as

```
  clickedValue:any;
  passValue(val:any){
      this.clickedValue = val;
      console.log(clickedVal);
  }
```

and then you can use the value , in any other form. 
Please ask for any clarification.

Comment: I'm not sure how would i implement that in typescript that js code

Comment: typescript is a flovour of js only, so all js codes work in typescript as well.So, Just add that to .ts file, it will work

Comment: I updated my code and i missed the row area wherein i need to get the value of the ENTIRE row and pass those values to a new form sorry